# C# how to fix SerializationException strange bug?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have this code:

```
public static void SaveData<T>(string filename, T playerData) where T : class
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    filename = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename;

    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filename))
        formatter.Serialize(stream, playerData);
}

public static T LoadData<T>(string filename) where T : class
{ 
    filename = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename;

    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
            return formatter.Deserialize(stream) as T;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("File not found...");
        return null;
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I have 2 static methods for serialization, deserialization any type of data.
First I'm serialize string (json) created by newtonsoft.json lib:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Wevent, Formatting.None);
SaveData<string>(fileName, json);
```

But then, then I'm trying to load same file back, I have Exception on this lines:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filename))
    formatter.Serialize(stream, playerData);
```

Full error message:

> SerializationException: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 5B-0D-0A-20-20-7B-0D-0A-20-20-20-20-22-54-65-78-74

Comment: Why are you serializing an already-serialized JSON string with `BinaryFormatter`?  Why not just write the string to disk?  If you did you could manually see what was wrong.  Also, can you [edit] your question to share a full [mcve]?  You wrote, * then I'm trying to load same file back, I have Exception on this lines:* but the code you show is also for serialization, not deserialization: `formatter.Serialize(stream, playerData);` so it's not clear even how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your lower code, titled with "loading back" is Code from the Save routine. And you should be able to read your file with a text viewer,since it's plain text. But there should be some header information in the beginning actually, saying: here comes a string. Is it really the written file ?

Comment: @dbc thx dude, just writing the string was good for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used @dbc answer:

" Why are you serializing an already-serialized JSON string with BinaryFormatter? Why not just write the string to disk? If you did you could manually see what was wrong. Also, can you edit your question to share a full minimal reproducible example? You wrote, * then I'm trying to load same file back, I have Exception on this lines:* but the code you show is also for serialization, not deserialization "

(I'm writed string to disk, and it was fine for me)